# How can I copy Facebook birthdays to my iPhone's calendar?

Tags: data-synchronization, calendar, facebook, ios

(Well, I've googled it but couldn't find anything useful. All the sources I've found were obsolete. iOS and Facebook are continuously changing over time.)

I'd like to sync the birthdays of my friends on Facebook with my calendar on my iPhone 6 with iOS 9.1. The reason why I want to do that is I don't want to check Facebook everyday to see if there is a birthday on that day. I use the calendar on my iPhone several times a day and it would be very handy to have Facebook birthdays on my calendar.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Are you signed into Facebook in iOS settings? There you should enable calendar and contacts. Then there should be two new calendars to see in the calendar app under the heading Facebook. At least that is how it's been working for some time and still on 9.1.

Comment: @Hoshts: Yes, I am signed into Facebook in iOS settings, but there is not any option on that screen regarding calendar.

Comment: That is weird. Mine have toggles like when you set up iCloud, where you can select what you should sync.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. Looks like I'll have to wait till someone provides a solution.